# Is DragonBones compatible with libGDX?

Tags: libgdx, dragonbone

I am trying to use DragonBone animations in my LibGDX game.

I am working on an endless runner game,so JSON levels will be loaded continuously and obstacles and coins get created each time level gets loaded.

Whenever I apply DragonBone animation for the obstacles,game is having a lag and white screen appears while executing code for collision.

Is DragonBone really compatible with LibGdx?
Or this problem occur because my code structure is not proper?(For each level,I am assigning DragonBone to each obstacles from a dragonBone array.Not able to use any loader for dragonBone also.Didn't get any code for that from net.)

Hope I will get some relevant suggestions.I am Really getting a hard time on this issue.

Comment: libgdx support [Spine](http://fr.esotericsoftware.com/), you should go with it.

Comment: there's a runtime https://github.com/DragonBones/DragonBonesJAVA/tree/master/dragonbones-libgdx